# Parâmetros do ajax estão vindo como undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Gostaria de  dizer que pesquisei no fórum e achei algumas perguntas semelhantes, porém nenhuma resposta solucionou o meu problema.  Segue a minha dúvida:

**Dúvida:**

Estou tentando excluir uma notificação pelo ajax, mas está ocorrendo o erro. As variáveis **id_projeto** e **n_notificacao** estão como **undefined**. Como solucionar este problema?

**Erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**ProjetoController.php:** (método ***removeNotificacao***)

```
//Este método remove a Notificação
        public function removeNotificacao(Request $request)
        {
            $notificacao = HistoricoNotificacao::find($request->id)->where('n_notificacao', '=',  $request->nnotificacao);

            $nnotificacao = $request->nnotificacao;
            if (!$notificacao)
            return response()
                        ->json(['error' => 'not_found'], 404);

            $response =  $notificacao->deletarNotificacao($notificacao);  

            if($response['success'])
            {
            return response()
                    ->json(['success' => $response['message']], 200);  

            }else
            {
                // Caso não delete, informa um erro inesperado
            return redirect()
            ->json(['error' => 'Erro ao remover a notificação nnotificacao ' + $nnotificacao ], 500);        
                        //->json(['error' => $response['message']], 500);        
            } 
        }
```

**Projeto.php:** (método ***deletarNotificacao***)

```
   //Este método remove os dados da Notificação
    public function deletarNotificacao(HistoricoNotificacao $notificacao) : Array
    {
        $notificacao = $this->delete();
        if($notificacao){
            return[
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Sucesso ao excluir a notificação'
            ];   
        }
        else{
            return[
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Falha ao excluir a notificação'
            ]; 
        }
    }
```

**Página Ajax**  (projeto-notificacao.js)

É responsável por passar as variáveis **id_projeto** e **n_notificacao** para o método **removeNotificacao**.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnExcluirNotificacao', function () {
    $('#idProjNotificacao').val($(this).data('id'));
    $('#numNotificacao').text($(this).data('nnotificacao'));
});

//Ajax para remover uma notificação, e atualizar a página após a ação
$('.removeNotificacao').click(function () {

    var data_id = $('#idProjNotificacao').val();
    var n_notificacao = $('#numNotificacao').val();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    }); 

    $.ajax({
        url:  "/projetos/removeNotificacao",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: data_id, nnotificacao: n_notificacao}
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        if (response.success) {  

        /*  $('.message').text("Sucesso ao excluir");
         $('.message').show();  */
        alert ('Sucesso ao excluir a notificação');

        setTimeout(function(){
                location.reload();
            }, 4000); 
        }
        else {
        //    alert(response.error);
        alert("Erro ao excluir a notificação");

        }   
    }).fail(function (response) {
      //  $('.message').text("Erro ao excluir");
      alert("Falha ao excluir a notificação , nnotificacao = " + response.nnotificacao + "  Id = "+response.id);
    });

    return false;
});




//Evento que preencherá o modal View de histórico de Notificações
$(document).on('click', '.btnViewNotificacao',function () {
    $('#modalViewIdNotificacao').val(($(this).data('id')));
    $('#modalViewNnotificacao').val(($(this).data('nnotificacao')));
    $('#modalViewDtRecebimento').val(($(this).data('dtrecebimento')));
    $('#modalViewDtResposta').val(($(this).data('dtresposta')));
    $('#modalViewConteudo').val(($(this).data('conteudo')));
    $('#modalViewOrigem').val(($(this).data('origem')));
    $('#modalViewDtConclusao').val(($(this).data('dtconclusao')));
});

//Evento que preencherá o modal Edit de histórico de Notificações
  $(document).on('click', '.btnEditNotificacao',function () {
    $('#modalEditIdNotificacao').val(($(this).data('id')));
    $('#modalEditNnotificacao').val(($(this).data('nnotificacao')));
    $('#modalEditDtRecebimento').val(($(this).data('dtrecebimento')));
    $('#modalEditDtResposta').val(($(this).data('dtresposta')));
    $('#modalEditConteudo').val(($(this).data('conteudo')));
    $('#modalEditOrigem').val(($(this).data('origem')));
    $('#modalEditDtConclusao').val(($(this).data('dtconclusao')));
});
```

**Modal Excluir Notificação**

```
<!-- Modal de Excluir Notificação-->
                <div class="modal fade modal-danger" id="modalExcluirNotificacao" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="examplePositionCenter"
                 role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-center">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Exclusão da Notificação</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                           <input type="hidden" id="idProjNotificacao"> 
                            <p>Deseja excluir a notificação de número "<span id="numNotificacao"></span>"?</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger removeNotificacao" data-dismiss="modal">Excluir</a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-pure" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Fim do Modal de Excluir Notificação -->
```

**Bibliotecas JavaScript da página edita.blade.php**

```
@section('adminlte_js')

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  

<!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

 <!--Inicio das interações em AJAX-->
     <script src="{{asset('js/pages-js/projeto/projeto-validaData.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/pages-js/projeto/projeto-cadNovasLocalidades.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/pages-js/projeto/projeto-autorizaProjeto.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/pages-js/projeto/projeto-autorizaDocs.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/pages-js/projeto/projeto-localidades.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/pages-js/projeto/projeto-create.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/pages-js/projeto/projeto-notificacao.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/pages-js/projeto/projeto-errata.js')}}"></script> 
    <!--Fim das interações em AJAX-->


     <script  src="{{asset('js/app-js.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- <script  src="{{asset('js/datatables/jquery-1.12.4.js')}}"></script>  -->
    <!--Inicio da biblioteca DataTables-->
    <!--  <script src="{{asset('js/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/datatables/buttons.flash.min.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/datatables/jszip.min.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/datatables/pdfmake.min.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/datatables/vfs_fonts.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/datatables/buttons.html5.min.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/datatables/buttons.print.min.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{asset('js/datatables/buttons.colVis.min.js')}}"></script>  -->
     <!--Fim da biblioteca DataTables -->  



    @yield('js')
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar:

```
var n_notificacao = $('#numNotificacao').html();
```

Comment: Obrigada, irei testar.

Comment: Fiz a modificação, mas o erro persiste.

Comment: Se o documento for xhtml, deve ser usado $('#numNotificacao').text();

Comment: Primeiramente obrigada pelo retorno. Eu fiz os testes no arquivo ajax e o mesmo está recebendo os valores das variáveis idProjNotificacao' e numNotificacao. O problema ocorre no controlador ProjetoController.php no momento de deletar os dados. Ao fazer o debug na aba network apareceu o seguinte erro quando eu usei o comando $response = $notificacao->delete(); : message: A non-numeric value encountered exception: ErrorException file: c:\xampp\htdocs\union\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProjetoController.php

Answer (score 1):

Não vi no código como você está definindo o atributo `data` do botão `#btnExcluirNotificacao`.

Mas você pode tentar assim e ver se funciona:

```
//Ajax para remover uma notificação, e atualizar a página após a ação
$('.removeNotificacao').click(function () {

    var data_id = $('#btnExcluirNotificacao').data('id');
    var n_notificacao = $('#btnExcluirNotificacao').data('nnotificacao');
```

Se não der certo, tente:

```
var data_id = $('#btnExcluirNotificacao').attr('data-id');
var n_notificacao = $('#btnExcluirNotificacao').attr('data-nnotificacao');
```

Comment: Leo Klaj, obrigada pela resposta. Eu fiz os testes como recomendado além disso testei os seguintes  códigos:                    
var data_id = $('#idProjNotificacao').val();                                         
var n_notificacao = $('#numNotificacao').val();  e  a  seguinte forma   var data_id = $('#idProjNotificacao').html(); var n_notificacao = $('#numNotificacao').html();   Mas o erro persiste. O erro está ocorrendo quando as variáveis id e nnotificacao é passado para o controlador (ProjetoController.php).

Comment: Então parece que o botão btnExcluirNotificacao não possui os atributos data definidos. Tente dar console.log para ver se os atributos estão lá mesmo.

Comment: Primeiramente obrigada pelo retorno. Eu fiz os testes no arquivo ajax e o mesmo está recebendo os valores das variáveis idProjNotificacao' e numNotificacao. O problema ocorre no controlador ProjetoController.php no momento de deletar os dados. Ao fazer o debug na aba network apareceu o seguinte erro quando eu usei o comando $response = $notificacao->delete(); : message: A non-numeric value encountered exception: ErrorException file: c:\xampp\htdocs\union\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProjetoController.php